# PHP Regex match multiple string combinations insinde a string and remove unwanted letters between all matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string with several lines of CSS code. I want to match all occurences of :

```
background:url(" url ");
```

and remove everything except the filename.

**Example input:**

```
background:url("http://external_link.com/images/my_suspicious_file.png");
background:url("rubish.com/images/my_suspicious_file.jpg");
background:url("retarded_input/folder/flodder/my_suspicious_file.gif");
```

**Expected output**

```
background:url("my_suspicious_file.png");
background:url("my_suspicious_file.jpg");
background:url("my_suspicious_file.gif");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search pattern:

```
background:url\(".*\/(.*?)"\);
```

Replace pattern:

```
background:url("$1");
```

You'll need to escape the strings above for PHP, and I'm assuming you are not using the `s` option (single line).

**Update**

With everything on the same line:

```
background:url\("[^"]*\/(.*?)"\);
```

Same replace pattern.

Comment: How would I go fourth if I would have everything on the same line?